# WPF. How to stop data trigger animation through binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding, wpfdatagrid

In WPF toolkit datagrid I have a data trigger bound to opacity of cell element.

When `UpVisibility` changes to 1 the path become visible and the animation starts to fade it to 0. Which works.

However my problem now - if I need to prematurely stop/cancel the fading and am setting `UpVisibility` to 0 the Path is still visible and fading as nothing happened....

**How to drop opacity to 0 instantly using MyValue object ?**

```
<Path Data="M 5,0 0,10 10,10" Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Green" Opacity="{Binding MyValue[0].UpVisibility}" Margin="5,0,5,0">
    <Path.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyValue[0].UpVisibility}" Value="1.0">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:10" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style> 
</Path>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried something like this (untested example):

```
<Path Data="M 5,0 0,10 10,10" Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Green" Opacity="{Binding MyValue[0].UpVisibility}" Margin="5,0,5,0">
    <Path.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyValue[0].UpVisibility}" Value="1.0">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:10" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
```

I set the animation duration to 0 to be instant. And if you don't define the From property you are instructing WPF to start in the current DependencyProperty value, so it will transition smoothly.

Answer (score 24):

Storyboards can also be stopped using the `ExitAction` on a `DataTrigger`, which is called when the bound value changes out of the target state. Just give your `BeginStoryboard` a name, and reference it in a `StopStoryboard` action, like so:

```
<DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard Name="your_storyboard_name">
        ...
    </BeginStoryboard>
</DataTrigger.EnterActions>

<DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="your_storyboard_name" />
</DataTrigger.ExitActions>
```

This may be more appropriate than starting a second storyboard to stop or mask a different storyboard.

Comment: This is what I was looking for because my storyboard is running forever so I needed to stop it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reset animation in code behind you usually do such call:

```
 MyControl.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, null);
```

But how to do it in XAML according to MVVM? Answer is:

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Vanishing}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation To="{x:Null}" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

To call animation in ViewModel we can do:

```
Vanishing = true;
await Task.Delay(500);
Vanishing = false;
```

Also make sure that binding property (Vanishing in my case) calls **INotifyPropertyChanged** to notify view about new value